# Azure AD B2C & Blazor Server .NET 8.0 How to Call Separate User SignIn & User SignUp UserFlows

Tags: blazor, azure-ad-b2c, .net-8.0

I currently have a Blazor app that uses Azure B2C and is working. It uses a combined user flow that is SignupSignIn (all in one). I created the user flows in azure AD B2C and modified the appsettings.json to this below:

```
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://login.example.com/",
    "Domain": "0000-0000-0000",
    "TenantId": "0000-0000-0000",
    "ClientId": "0000-0000-0000",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignIn",
    "SignUpPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUp",
    //"SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_susi",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_susi",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_reset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_edit",
    "EnablePiiLogging": true
  },
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

appsettings.json

This is my program.cs related the Azure AD B2C:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.Configure<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = (context) =>
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(context.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri);
        context.HandleResponse();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

Program.cs

I am sure I am missing something.

This is how I currently call the combined SignUpSignIn:

```
Navigation.NavigateTo("MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn");
```

This works for "SignUpSignInPolicyId". How do I get it to call the other userflows?
How do I call the "SignInPolicyId" & "SignUpPolicyId" from with in Blazor? Thanks for any help!